# How to integrate AEM with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aem

I have been through all the sites currently available to refer AEM & ElasticSearch, but could not find anything exact which is related to integration of these both.

Requirement : To create site search functionality for publish which will bring out all the results which are related to particular keyword. Currently we are using default AEM site search functionality, which very slow and thus we want to migrate it to ES. There are very less documents available on   integration of these both, so we are troubling with it. Mainly we have to do this In Java.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are question is very vague. You have not specified what is it that you are trying to achieve. Do you want you the search results on the AEM publish side to be served by Elastic Search or do you want all your content(even in AEM author to be indexed?). There are multiple patterns hence it is not possible to provide a general answer. There are multiple ways you can integrate.

1) write custom replication agents in AEM to push content to ES.

2) create a workflow which can be triggered with launchers whenever node is added/modified. I would suggest you to refrain from this and consider option 1 instead as this will trigger too many workflow instances and will impact overall performance.

3) You can write crawlers to crawl your aem publish  & index the content in ES.

4) you can write code which runs in ES(river in ES terminology) to fetch the content from AEM & index it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete implementation of Apache Solr, Elasticsearch and Apache Lucene with AEM 6.5 - https://github.com/tadijam64/search-engines-comparison

There is detailed explanation of how every search engine works, and how it is integrated with AEM - step by step explained in six write-ups [here](https://github.com/tadijam64/search-engines-comparison/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Its an old repo but may help you with the integration..
https://github.com/viveksachdeva/elasticsearch-cq

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an old question but I had the same problem and came up with a new implementation you can find on github:

https://github.com/deveth0/elasticsearch-aem

The usage is quite easy, you have to include several bundles and then configure, which Elasticsearch Instance to use. 
Upon Page-Activation AEM triggers a Replication Agent that pushes the data to Elasticsearch.

For more detailed information, have a look at my [blog](https://www.dev-eth0.de/blog/2017/01/18/elasticsearch-aem.html)

Comment: That's actually useful. I gone through your blog and it actually resemble what i am looking for. Thank you :)